# Javascript closure (this)

Tags: javascript, closures, this

I have already looked everywhere on stackoverflow, but couldn't find any answer for this.

Uncaught TypeError: this.rsGame is not a function (same about this.addEnemy)

```
let game = new Phaser.Game(600,600);
let speed = 500;


let scyla = {

    preload: () => {
      game.load.image('bg', 'assets/bg.png');
      game.load.image('pl', 'assets/pl.png');
      game.load.image('enemy', 'assets/enemy.png');

    },
    create: () => {

      game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE)

      game.add.sprite(0,0, 'bg');

      this.player = game.add.sprite(300, 500, 'pl');
      this.player.anchor.set(0.5);

      game.physics.arcade.enable(this.player);
      this.cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

      this.enemies = game.add.group();

      // this.timer = game.time.events.loop(200, this.addEnemy(), this);
    },
    update: () => {

      this.player.body.velocity.x = 0;
      this.player.body.velocity.y = 0;

      if (this.cursors.left.isDown)
          this.player.body.velocity.x = speed * -1;

      if (this.cursors.right.isDown)
          this.player.body.velocity.x = speed;

      if (this.cursors.up.isDown)
          this.player.body.velocity.y = speed * -1;

      if (this.cursors.down.isDown)
          this.player.body.velocity.y = speed;

      if (this.player.inWorld === false)
          this.rsGame(); 
    },
    rsGame: () => {
      game.state.start('scyla');

    },
    addEnemy: () => {
      let enemy = game.add.sprite(300, 100, 'enemy');
      game.physics.arcade.enable(enemy);
      enemy.body.gravity.y = 200;

      this.enemies.add(enemy);
      enemy.checkWorldBounds = true;
      enemy.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    }
}

game.state.add('scyla', scyla);
game.state.start('scyla');
```

I tried things like

```
let self = this
```

this return the windows object anyway. This has something to do with closure, but I don't understand exactly

don't know how to solve this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function set `this` to the *lexical* scope. You're trying to access the `scyla` object but the arrow function is setting it to `window` (or whatever `this` is equal to at the time that you declare `scyla`).

Either reference `scyla` directly:

```
scyla.rsGame();
```

or write your methods using standard function expressions:

```
update: function() {
    ...
    if (this.player.inWorld === false)
        this.rsGame(); 
}
```

or shorthand method declarations:

```
update() {
    ...
    if (this.player.inWorld === false)
        this.rsGame();
}
```

Comment: Or concise method declarations: `update() {`

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions preserve the value of `this` from when they are declared.

Use a regular function expression. Don't use arrow functions for this.

```
preload: function preload () { 
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions have lexically scoped `this`. You need to use regular functions in your case so that `this` gets binded as usual. Change:

```
update: () => {
```

To:

```
update: function ( ) {
```

and similarly for the other properties of `scyla`.